# Devcomponents SuperGrid Primary column not set

Tags: datagridview, components

hi

i use dotnetbar supergrid fo winform but i cant set my desired column as primary column to show tree buttons and lines .i fill gridwiew in my cod and not by binding to data source.there is some rows where each have some sub rows but tree button is not shown

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it . first added column have been considered as primary column . but in my code it does not work beceuse i was added some columns manually in designer .although i was removed them but it seems some data about that removed columns was saved somewhere .so there was some hidden columns in my gridview .i delete control and add just a new one